# How to remove branding from tire?

Tags: tire

I have bought a new tire. It has big white labeling on each side which I don't like.

Do you know any method to remove this white text from the tire?

[image]

Comment: I think that you have actually *paid* to advertise for them.

Comment: Either black it out with a Sharpie or tire paint, or use a sander to remove the white.  For a sander you'd probably want a Dremel with a sanding wheel or a detail sander.  A wire brush might also work.

Comment: (Of course, it's one of those PITA folding tires anyway, so I'd be tempted to just toss it out.)

Comment: Does this bother you for other things you own?

Comment: Have you tried putting on your bike yet? Have a go first and see how much it stands out.

Comment: I'd not suggest a sander cause you'd risk weakening the sidewalls.

Comment: Another idea is to just ignore form, fashion and colours (looking at your bike) and focus on function, performance, improving your skills and having fun (riding your bike).

Comment: Not an answer, but still. Large white logos are good for side visibility by motorists.

Comment: @Vorac they're nothing compared to the reflective bands on my Schwalbe Road Cruisers

Comment: This seems to be a racing tire, it has very thin sidewalls, try not to damage them.

Comment: Its now many years later - how did you get on ?  Did you succeed in hiding the white writing?  Was it effective?   SE permits and encourages answering your own question.

Answer (score 8):

In the words of the Rolling Stones: Paint It Back. You may need to experiment to find something durable but it should be quite easy to find something suitable.

Comment: Ach, you beat me to it! I would try a thick sharpie, or one of those giant-ass big black markers they use in the post office to black out labels on packages. Make sure you have ventilation! You'll likely have to reapply over time.

Comment: Be careful in what you choose to paint the tire. You don't want anything that might degrade the rubber.

Comment: You might find this tire paint in an auto parts store. http://www.autogeek.net/forblactirge.html

Answer (score 2):

[This option](http://www.millertire.com/repairs.asp) might be more money than it is worth. [This option](http://www.niagaralubricant.com/0839TirePaint.htm) as well might be more money than it is worth ...

But the question is ... HOW much does this bother you? 5 gallons of paint worth of bother? Hahah.

Answer (score 2):

Some black spray paint should do the job for you. Just a light coat, enough to make the white lettering disappear, should last a long time.